# Json Validation with PlayFramework in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Can someone please help me to fix the following code:

```
  case class Person(name:String,email:Option[String]) 
  implicit val personFormat:Format[Person] = (
      (__ \ "name").format[String] ~
      (__ \ "email").formatNullable[String](email) // The code doesn't compile here
    )(Person.apply,unlift(Person.unapply))
```

Apparently FormatNullable doesn't work with ReadConstraints, how can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`email` is a `Read[String]` while you require a `Format[String]` here. `Format` is a combination of `Read` and `Write` for cases where they are **symmetrical**. This isn't the case here because validation is only for reading JSON, not for writing it. So you cannot write a single `Format`.

To get around this, write your `Read` and `Write` separately:

```
implicit val personReads: Reads[Person] = (
  (JsPath  \ "name").read[String] ~ 
  (JsPath  \ "email").readNullable[String](email)
)(Person.apply _)

implicit val personWrites: Writes[Person] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] ~
  (JsPath \ "email").writeNullable[String]
)(unlift(Person.unapply))

implicit val personFormat: Format[Person] = 
  Format(personReads,personWrites)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, actually I noticed that
when I change formatNullable[String](email) to format[String](email), it works. It only stops working when I use formatNullable.

Comment: Ah ok, that kind of contradicts the docs then. :D I believe that they might have added that possibility to `format` for convenience but forgot to add it to `formatNullable`. But that is just a wild guess.

Comment: I also think the same, I'll accept the answer. Thanks